# Groovy GroupBy Variable KeySet

Tags: java, groovy, closures

I am struggling with using groovy groupBy

I need to support grouping a dataset by a variable key set.

I have written a test to explain my predicament, and would love some help understanding how to implement it:

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5155615986941952

```
List<Map> people = [
    [
        Sex: "Male",
        Age: 30,
        Job: "Programmer",
        Name: "Boris"
    ],
    [
        Sex: "Female",
        Age: 30,
        Job: "Programmer",
        Name: "Jennifer"
    ],
    [
        Sex: "Male",
        Age: 40,
        Job: "Web Designer",
        Name: "Bob"
    ],
    [
        Sex: "Female",
        Age: 20,
        Job: "Database Admin",
        Name: "Alice"
    ]
]


List results = []
if(people.groupBy({it.Sex}, {it.Age}) != groupBySpecifiedCols(people, ["Sex", "Age"])){
  return "Failed 1"
}

if(people.groupBy({it.Sex}, {it.Age}, {it.Job}) != groupBySpecifiedCols(people, ["Sex", "Age", "Job"])){
  return "Failed 2"
}

def groupBySpecifiedCols(List<Map> data, List<String> columns){
  // IMPLEMENT HERE

  return null
}


return "Success!"​​​​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think I just solved it, after hours of frustration it turned out simple:

```
def groupBySpecifiedCols(List<Map> data, List<String> columns){
  List<Closure> groupByClosures = []
  columns.each{ column ->
    groupByClosures << { it[column] }
  }

  return data.groupBy(groupByClosures)
}
```

**EDIT** as pointed out in comments, there is a potentially more concise way:

```
def groupBySpecifiedCols(List<Map> data, List<String> columns){
  return data.groupBy(columns.collect{ col -> ((Closure){ it[col] })})
}
```

Comment: How embarassing, found the answer while I was cleaning up the test for SO...

Hope this at least helps someone else in future

Comment: That `each`+`<<` can be written with `collect`.

Comment: Yeah, the body of your function could be replaced with: `data.groupBy columns.collect { column -> { it."$column" } }`

Comment: Thanks, added to answer - but had to cast to avoid ambiguity error in compilation

Comment: Ahhhh... Or use `{ it -> it."$column" }` so groovy knows it's a closure